# "Controllers polluting the Global Namespace" what does it mean in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie to `Angular.js` , i have read that Controllers should not pollute the global namespace.

What does it really means

and why `angular.module('SomeApp',[]).controller('SomeController', function($scope) {})`

is the best way to add a controller?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Polluting the global namespace is not specific to Angular, but to Javascript (and actually any dynamic-typed language, where variables could appear or be redeclared in almost any scope).

Polluting the global namespace would make unavailable -actually: will override- certain names among modules.

Imagine I have a module A in 'a.js' where I declare:

```
mymodule = angular.module('A');

function Foo($s, $http){ ... };
foo = mymodule.controller('foo', ['$scope', Foo]);
```

Also imagine I included, beforehand, a script named 'utils.js':

```
foo = 3;
```

`foo` in a.js would override `foo` in my utils script. That is polluting the global namespace and that's why it's a bad idea (perhaps I actually NEEDED the foo var).

Want to have code like that instead of chaining the calls? use a closure:

```
/* a.js */
(function(){
    var mymodule = angular.module('A');

    function Foo($s, $http){ ... };
    var foo = mymodule.controller('foo', ['$scope', Foo]);
})();
```

And so, you will not pollute the global namespace since each declaration is inside the anonymous function call.

Answer (score 2):

That format you used

```
angular.module('SomeApp',[]).controller('SomeController', function($scope) {})
```

does not pollute the global namespace.

---

This format would however:

**Javascript**

```
function UserController($scope) { ... }
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="UserController">
```

---

That is because the controller function is globally available outside of the scope of the angular application